# Create new X509 certificate in swift on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, security, cryptography

My use case is below.
 1. I need to create new X509 certificates on iOS device when user opens app for the first time.
 2. I need the code doing this in swift using Security framework.
 3. Is this supported on iOS security framework without the usage of thirdparty libs?
 4. If answer to the point #3 above is no, then which thisrdparty libs can I use?

Comment: Just use openssl bindings for swift

Comment: @Woodstock Thanks for the information. is there no support by iOS Security Framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a certificate with the `Security.framework`. What you need to do manually is prepend the x509 Header to it.

The snippets I will post below are simplified examples. Ensure you deal with `nil` values responsibly.

The following code will generate a certificate:

```
  func obtainKeyData(_ tag: String) -> Data {
      var keyRef: AnyObject?
      let query: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
          String(kSecAttrKeyType): kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
          String(kSecReturnData): kCFBooleanTrue as CFBoolean,
          String(kSecClass): kSecClassKey as CFString,
          String(kSecAttrApplicationTag): tag as CFString,
      ]

      switch SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &keyRef) {
      case noErr:
        return keyRef as! Data
      default:
        fatalError("Error")
      }
  }
```

Now you need to prepend a x509 header to it. You can do with a `Data` category:

```
extension Data {
  public func dataByPrependingX509Header() -> Data {
      let result = NSMutableData()

      let encodingLength: Int = (self.count + 1).encodedOctets().count
      let OID: [CUnsignedChar] = [0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86,
          0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00]

      var builder: [CUnsignedChar] = []

      // ASN.1 SEQUENCE
      builder.append(0x30)

      // Overall size, made of OID + bitstring encoding + actual key
      let size = OID.count + 2 + encodingLength + self.count
      let encodedSize = size.encodedOctets()
      builder.append(contentsOf: encodedSize)
      result.append(builder, length: builder.count)
      result.append(OID, length: OID.count)
      builder.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

      builder.append(0x03)
      builder.append(contentsOf: (self.count + 1).encodedOctets())
      builder.append(0x00)
      result.append(builder, length: builder.count)

      // Actual key bytes
      result.append(self)

      return result as Data
  }
}
```

Finally, combine the two together to create certificates with the x509 format:

```
let x509Key = obtainKeyData(keyTag).dataByPrependingX509Header()
```

For reference, I got this code from the [Heimdall](https://github.com/henrinormak/Heimdall) project, a `Security` framework wrapper for Swift, and it's currently being used in a private app.

Comment: How can I store this `x509Key` as a String? Cause when I try, it shows me that It's Data.

Comment: Also, to mention, `obtainKeyData(keyTag)` is crashing in my case in `fatalError("Error")`.

I'm using `SwiftyRSA` to generate `RSA`

Answer (score 1):

There are two new open source Swift packages: swift-certificates and swift-asn1. Together, these libraries provide developers a faster and safer implementation of X.509 certificates, a critical technology that powers the security of TLS.

Swift Certificates has been released at an early stage.

https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-certificates-and-asn1/